# ConcurrentModificationException in java

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

edit: problem solved, it came indeed from the sublist. Thanks!

I am doing a project about genetic algorithms.
but I have the entitled error, and I don't really know where it happens, so I would need your help...

here is the function:

```
public synchronized void evolution(){
    //TreeSet containing the 2 fathers and children
    TreeChromosome t = new TreeChromosome();
    Chromosome father1 = selection();
    Chromosome father2;
    do{father2= selection();}
    while(father1==father2);

    t.add(father1);
    t.add(father2);


    Chromosome child1 = OperatorGen.crossRight(father1, father2);
    OperatorGen.swap(father1);

    Chromosome child2 = OperatorGen.crossLeft(father1, father2);        
    OperatorGen.swap(child2);

    t.add(fils1);
    t.add(fils2);

    // we add the best 2 in the population 
       Chromosome best1=t.pollFirst();
       genotype.add(best1);
        Chromosome best2=t.pollFirst();
       genotype.add(best2);

    //we remove the non selected chromosomes
    for (Chromosome chromo : t) {
        if (genotype.contains(chromo) && t.contains(chromo)){
            genotype.remove(chromo);
        }
    }
    genotype.updateRanks();
}
```

when I run this, it works fine but when I run this in a loop, I have the exception on OperatorGen.crossLeft ...
here is the code of this function:

```
public static Chromosome crossLeft(Chromosome father1, Chromosome father2, int joint){
    List<Ville> listFather1 = father1.getCities();
    List<Ville> listFather2 = pere2.getCities();
    //we copy the first cities of father1
    List<Ville> listChild= listPere1.subList(0, joint);
    City nextCity;
    //we add the cities of father2  
    //block where the error appears, not always at the same line

  for(int i=0;i<listFather2.size();i++){           
        nextCity=listFather2.get(i);

        if(!listChild.contains(nextCity)){
            listChild.add(nextCity);
        }
    }
    Chromosome child= new Chromosome(listChild);
    return child;
 }
```

I tried adding syncronized everywhere but nothing works... So I would like to know where is the problem and how do I correct it?
Thank you!

Comment: Where is your `genotype`-instance declared?

Comment: in the class containing the first function:
      private static TreeChromosome genotype = new TreeChromosome();

Comment: You must provide a full stack trace. Also indicate what the line numbers are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove from a collection you are currently iterating over, unless you use the `Iterator.remove()` method, which requires that you don't use the enhanced for-loop.

Comment: You sure this is the case? He is iterating over `t`, but removing from `genotype`, which from my understanding are separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughout your code you keep re-using the same cities, as well as the same Lists. When you use subList, you are actually creating a view on the old list ( [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int, int])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) ). It is no wonder that when you work all those lists concurrently, you get a ConcurrentModificationException.

You must either be very carefull with these lists (to really see where it goes wrong, we'd probably need the entire source code). Or you must create new List-instances instead of the subList.

By the way, the way you translated about half the french made it less easy to read your code rather than easier.. (pere-father, child-fils, etc..)

Comment: sorry about that =)
and thank you, I will modify this then. 
I don't really understand why it works when I run this function, but not when I call it in a while(true) for example...